# What should you do when your question has already been asked, but none of the answers work?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

What should you do if your question has already been asked, and you've tried all of the answers but they either didn't work, or wouldn't be acceptable solutions in your situation? Should you:

1. Open a new question, explain all of the solutions you've tried, and reference the duplicate question?
2. Open a bounty on the existing question?